# Javascript grid click to re-organize

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project and have gotten stuck on reorganizing my grid via JQuery. I've broken the problem down into a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tylerbuchea/QgAqV/

```
$('div').bind('click', function() {
   var pitcher = $('.selected')[0];
   var catcher = this;

  if (catcher.offsetTop < pitcher.offsetTop || catcher.offsetLeft > pitcher.offsetLeft) {
    $(pitcher).before(catcher);
    console.log('before');
  } 

   else 
     if (catcher.offsetTop > pitcher.offsetTop || catcher.offsetLeft < pitcher.offsetLeft) {
       $(pitcher).after(catcher);
       console.log('after');
     }
});​
```

I want the "selected" div to move to clicked divs location with all other divs being scooted down (or up). This works fine, but if you try to move it more than one space... Well you'll see the problem. Maybe the .before and .after functions aren't what I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code example with [My Version](http://jsfiddle.net/QgAqV/6/):

```
$('div').bind('click', function() {
   var $currentlySelected = $('.selected'),
       $newlyClicked = $(this),
       currentlySelectedIndex = $currentlySelected.index(),
       newlyClickedIndex = $newlyClicked.index();

    if (currentlySelectedIndex > newlyClickedIndex) {
        $currentlySelected.insertBefore($newlyClicked);
        console.log('is greater, so put it after');
    } else {
        $currentlySelected.insertAfter($newlyClicked);
        console.log('is less, so put it after');
    }
});​
```

Have a look at this and tell me if it's doing what you want. I changed your logic around a little bit. The first thing I did was instead of checking offsets, I'm using .index() which tells me the position of an element in relation to its siblings.

If the clicked elements index is less than the currently selected elements index, then I move the currently selected element to BEFORE the clicked element so it takes its place. If the index of the clicked element is more than the currently selected elements index, then I move the currently selected element to AFTER the clicked element so it takes its place.

In regards as to why your elements were moving one at a time, I'm not entirely sure, but my guess would be that you were moving raw DOM elements around at times, and not jQuery objects. If they had ID's perhaps it would have been different. In any case, by moving around jQuery objects, it's working as intended.

Let me know if this is what your looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your cuestion, but think this is what you want:

```
$('div').bind('click', function() {
   var pitcher = $('.selected')[0];
   var catcher = this;

  if (catcher.offsetTop < pitcher.offsetTop || catcher.offsetLeft > pitcher.offsetLeft) {
    $(catcher).after(pitcher);
    console.log('before');
  } 

   else 
     if (catcher.offsetTop > pitcher.offsetTop || catcher.offsetLeft < pitcher.offsetLeft) {
        $(catcher).before(pitcher);
       console.log('after');
     }
});​
```

Regards,
Romén

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').bind('click', function() {
   var pitcher = $('.selected')[0];
   var catcher = this;

  if (catcher.offsetTop < pitcher.offsetTop || catcher.offsetLeft > pitcher.offsetLeft) {
    $(catcher).after(pitcher);
    console.log('before');
  }

   else
     if (catcher.offsetTop > pitcher.offsetTop || catcher.offsetLeft < pitcher.offsetLeft) {
        $(catcher).before(pitcher);
       console.log('after');
     }
});
```

You have inverted both the conditions and the use of the functions. Have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/before/) on how to use before()/after().

The code still does not work when you have multiple rows since there is a conceptual flow: you have to test if the catcher is before/after the pitcher in logical terms.

When a tile comes before another?

- when it is on an upper row
- **OR**
- when it is on the same row **AND** it is on the left

I leave the rest to you as an exercise